# ¿En entornos virtuales de Python, por qué la pip list es diferente dentro de la carpeta Scripts que dentro del entorno mismo?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Estoy aprendiendo Django y los entornos virtuales de Python, justo hice mi primer entorno virtual con venv (python 3) usando la consola CMD.

Cuando hago un *pip list* en cualquier otra carpeta de Windows me salen las librerías que normalmente tengo instaladas, y cuando hago *pip list* dentro de la carpeta Scripts me salen las librerías de entorno.

Entiendo que de eso se trata el entorno virtual, de tener módulos diferentes en mi entorno virtual para poder trabajar con distintos módulos. Pero no logro comprender por qué sucede esto? Más raro me parece que tenga distintas librerías pero sólo en la carpeta de Scripts, por qué?

Answer (score 1):

La razón es que el pip que estás ejecutando en cada caso es diferente.

En Windows, cuando escribes el nombre de un comando en la consola, el sistema debe encontrar el ejecutable en el disco, para lo cual no busca el disco completo (sería muy ineficiente), sino una serie de carpetas predefinidas.

Para empezar comienza siempre buscando en la carpeta actual. Si encuentra ahí el ejecutable que buscaba, ya no busca más. Si no está en la carpeta actual seguirá buscando por la lista de carpetas especificadas en una variable de entorno llamada PATH. Puedes ver el valor de esa variable en la consola poniendo `echo %PATH%`. En esa variable están separadas por `;` todos los nombres de carpeta donde buscará. Se quedará con la primera en la que aparezca. Si no aparece en ninguna te dirá eso de "comando no encontrado.

Cuando estás dentro de la carpeta `Scripts`, el pip que ejecutará será precisamente el que está dentro de esa carpeta, y no busca más (pues dentro de `Scripts` hay un `pip.exe`)

Si estás fuera de la carpeta Scripts, entonces el pip que ejecute será el primero que encuentre en el PATH. Se ve que en tu caso ese es otro diferente.

El caso es que el comportamiento de `pip` depende de en qué carpeta concreta está el ejecutable, pues si `pip` detecta que el ejecutable `pip.exe` estaba dentro de una carpeta de un entorno virtual, entonces listará los paquetes instalados en ese entorno virtual (o si lo usas con `pip install` instalará paquetes en ese entorno virtual). Por el contrario, si el `pip.exe` invocado no estaba en un entorno virtual listará los paquetes instalados a nivel de sistema (y si lo usas con `pip install`, instalará a nivel de sistema).

Un entorno virtual no es más que una carpeta que contiene copias de `pip.exe`, `python.exe` y algunas herramientas más en una estructura específica, y en ella también estarán paquetes python que serán usados cuando se ejecute ese `python.exe` específico.

Normalmente, para evitar tener que especificar la ruta al `python.exe` o `pip.exe` que quieres ejecutar, el entorno virtual debe "activarse". Esta acción consiste simplemente en ejecutar un script que modifica el PATH para poner en primera posición la carpeta donde están los ejecutables para ese entorno. De ese modo, una vez activado, al poner `python` o `pip` los ejecutables que se usarán serán los del entorno (sin que importe ya si estás o no dentro de `Scripts`, pues serán encontrados de todas formas gracias a la modificación del PATH).

Esa modificación del PATH dura solo hasta que cierres esa terminal. Si abres una terminal nueva deberás "activar" de nuevo el entorno.

Comment: jutsu de invocacion, idioma parsel maestro de las serpientes abulafia, espero funcione la invocacion

Comment: @JackNavaRow (*puff*) Eh? dónde estoy?

Comment: naaj era pa saludar como no te veia en el chat, un saludo binario del lado de este charco!

Comment: Pues un saludo desde este lado del charco! Es cierto que hace la tira que no me paso por el chat. Saluda al resto de mi parte :-)